# Unable to generate utf-8 request in .net core on consuming a wcf with basic transport http binding with certificate authentication

Tags: .net-core, wcf-binding, xml-binding

I am consuming a wsdl described as :

```
<wsdl:binding name="PassengerConformance_v1Binding"
    type="tns:PassengerConformanceAuthenticationPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="identify">
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

But the request getting generated is UTF16, which the server wants to be utf-8
This is how my code looks

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
 {
     Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
     {
         Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
         Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
         {
             ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest
         }
     }
 };     
 var address = new EndpointAddress(dcsServiceConfiguration.Url);     
 var channel = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, address);     
 channel.Credentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential =
      new NetworkCredential(username, Password);     
 var buildDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 var filePath = buildDir + @"\ClientCert.pfx";     
 channel.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate =
     new X509Certificate2(filePath, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);  

 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;     
 return channel;
```

I understand that BasicHttpBinding deafult textEncoding value is utf-8, but still when I check in the message inspector, it comes to be utf-16.

I noticed that when I replicated this code in .net 7.2 framework consoel app, there was no xml tag. which would still work for me
Please help.

Comment: What errors do you got when you consume the service by using ChannelFacotory? Have you tried to invoke the service by adding service reference with Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider?
Besides, as far as I know, except we should establish the trust relationship between the server and the client, when we use Basichttpbinding to authenticate the client with a certificate, we need to set the default Certificate (service certificate) additionally.
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate

Comment: The handshake is successful. it is when i call the operation, the request is built with UTF-16 with response as <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Comment: The generated request when copied to soapui project and I change the encoding to utf-8 , it works.

Comment: What are the details of the error when you consume the service by using ChannelFactory? Have you tried to invoke the service by adding service reference with Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider?

Comment: Using preview for .net core 3 helped resolve the issue.